# CSS file and line number not showing while debugging rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, developer-tools

I'm trying to integrate a bootstrap template on `rails 4.2.1` application. When I inspect certain element to see it's css file and line number on browser's developers tool it is supposed to show the css file and line number as shown below:
[image]

Instead it is showing something like below:
[image]

I went through the problem and found that it is generating extra three style tags as shown below:
[image]

Here's my `application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>title</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="javascripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

and `application.css`

```
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

and `application.js`

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

All `css` and `js` files are included in `stylesheets` and `javascripts` folders respectively

Does anyone have idea what's wrong here?

Comment: can you post your layout,view and application.css file?

Comment: Please, refer to the updated question.

Comment: are you using any additional style-related gems?

Comment: @Grammakov I'm using just default gems. Not any other style-related gems.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the link to your page for a better perspective.

Comment: @AnkurMishra Sorry, it's currently on localhost only and when pushed to production I'll update the post with link

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you add the stylesheets inside `<style> </style>` tag. You might have added style sheets inside any of your view template.
[image]

It should have added the style link like

```
stylesheet_link_tag "style", media: "all"
# => <link href="/assets/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```